# Splicing Large Geometry into Smaller Geometries for Export in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I've been working on a task for a few days that involved iterating geometries and exporting time series data within these geometries. I want to be able to create a 1000 km^2 tile and then produce 100 tiles that are 100km^2 within this larger tile. Within the smaller tiles I want to export NDVI time series data to my Google Drive.

The desired output is 100 .tif file exports for a large area that can then be further analyzed in a different data processor.

This is the code that I am working with ("point" can be defined arbitrarily):

```
var targetArea = ee.Number(1e12)

function toSquare(buffer) {
  return point.buffer(buffer, 1).bounds()
}

function getBuffer(area) {
  return ee.Number(area).sqrt().divide(2)
}

var buffer = getBuffer(targetArea)
var minBuffer = buffer.multiply(0.99)
var maxBuffer = buffer.multiply(1.01)
var square, area
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  var buffer = minBuffer.add(maxBuffer).divide(2)
  square = toSquare(buffer)
  area = square.area(1)
  minBuffer = ee.Number(ee.Algorithms.If(area.lt(targetArea), buffer, minBuffer))
  maxBuffer = ee.Number(ee.Algorithms.If(area.gt(targetArea), buffer, maxBuffer))
}

print(area, 'area')
var perimeter = square.perimeter(.001);
print(perimeter, 'perimeter');
Map.addLayer(square)
Map.centerObject(square)
```

This is the link to the script pasted above and it creates a roughly 1km^2 tile with the data that I want to be exported:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/c48fb6bf2bbc8bc0511d95ab9c360fdb

The obvious problem is that the export would be too large for Earth Engine to handle at higher quality. Is there a way to break this down into smaller tiles through some sort of loop? I want the tiles to touch, so that no data is left out within the large square.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Earth Engine will automatically create tiles of your export if it is large.  Make sure you include the `maxPixels: yourMaxPixelsHere` so that it doesn't fail on you.  When you export, you are allowed a much larger amount of data, but you will have to be prepared to wait.

From the Google Earth Engine Developers Guide.

> If the output image is large, it will be exported as multiple files.
>   If you are exporting to GeoTIFF(s), the image is split into tiles. The
>   filename of each tile will be in the form baseFilename-yMin-xMin where
>   xMin and yMin are the coordinates of each tile within the overall
>   bounding box of the exported image.